# How to open a web site after uninstallation in non-elevated mode?

Tags: inno-setup

Having used the code posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31182438/9309385) to launch a web page after uninstall, I note that `ShellExec` starts the browser with the elevated credentials used by default by the Programs and Features control panel when starting the uninstaller.

Using [`ShellExecAsOriginalUser`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_execasoriginaluser) is documented as not possible during uninstall, and the suggestion made [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13986690/9309385) does not seem to be applicable in the case of wanting to access a URL.

Any suggestions on how to handle this?

Comment: FWIW, I find this behavior to be annoying. (I don't want a web page to open automatically when I uninstall something.)

Answer (score 2):

Based on [How to run exe with/without elevated privileges from PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29266622/850848), this seem to do the trick:

```pascal
Exec('explorer', 'https://www.example.com/', '', SW_SHOW, ewNoWait, ErrorCode);
```

---

I believe it works, because while the code obviously runs `explorer` process elevated, the Explorer does not allow multiple instances. So the new instance will just ask the existing instance of explorer (which is not elevated) to open the URL. The existing non-elevated instance of Explorer will run non-elevated instance of the web browser.

It's similar to how the web browsers themselves work. If you run `chrome url` (or any other browser) from an elevated process (like the un/installer), if no Chrome process is running yet, the URL opens in new elevated Chrome browser. But if some Chrome process is already running, the new elevated process will just ask the existing non-elevated process to open the URL.

The only difference is that while there is not always some web browser process running, *there is always an (unelevated) Explorer process*. And actually, even if there's not, [Explorer de-elevates itself](https://superuser.com/q/882075/213663#comment2483184_1626422).